# Add custom column at custom posts list

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-list-table, screen-columns

I want to have a column (e.g Send Email) in my custom posts (books) list.
In each row there should be a button (Send) and when I click on it I want to send an email.

I have seen is a hook [manage_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) to add custom column but this hook only adds post meta as columns like featured image etc.

How to do this, please help me.

---

Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Adding A New Column To The `books` Post Table

Here we can use the filters

```
manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_custom_column
manage_{$post->post_type}_posts_columns
```

or for the `books` post type:

```
manage_books_posts_custom_column
manage_books_posts_columns
```

Here's an example how we could display a button, for each row in the `send_email` column:

```
/**
 * Books Post Table: Display a utton in each row in the 'send_email' column
 */
add_action( 'manage_books_posts_custom_column', function ( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    if ( $column_name == 'send_email')
        printf( '<input type="button" value="%s" />', esc_attr( __( 'Send Email' ) ) );

}, 10, 2 );
```

To add the `send_email` column we can use:

```
/**
 * Books Post Table: Add the 'send_email' column
 */
add_filter('manage_books_posts_columns', function ( $columns ) 
{
    if( is_array( $columns ) && ! isset( $columns['send_email'] ) )
        $columns['send_email'] = __( 'Send Email' );     
    return $columns;
} );
```

We could also limit the column width with:

```
/**
 * Limit the 'send_email' column width
 */
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-edit.php', function()
{        
    echo '<style> .column-send_email { width: 100px; }</style>';
} );
```

Here's an example output:

[image: button]

You will then have to implement how the button will work.

ps: I removed the second part from my answer, since that part of your question, would be better served as a new separate question.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer friend. 1) Button successfully added :) can you please also let me know how to keep it at right side with equal to button width only, I have attached screenshot for better understanding. 2) Second answer is not exactly clear, I do not want to remove Draft , I want to remove "- post_status", see screenshot.

Comment: Looks like your part #2 regarding post status has been solved. I added a hack to adjust the column width. @BhuvneshGupta