# Customize WP_List_Table inside admin panel

Tags: wp-list-table

I need to make some changes exactly inside the WordPress panel. More specifically on a page that lists a specific post list.

I need to add a custom search field with a specific field.
I need also to add a few more columns in the same table.
I checked the [wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table). But it is very superficial, not very explanatory.

Has anyone had to?

Comment: WPSE has a lot of q/a about this topic, please use the search.
A example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220158/add-custom-column-at-custom-posts-list , http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253640/adding-custom-columns-to-custom-post-types , http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11758/extending-the-search-context-in-the-admin-list-post-screen